# React material-ui responsive layout

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I am trying to use material-ui in my React application. The components are great, but it doesn't seem like they were designed to be responsive. For example, I'm trying to implement the Drawer component in my home page like this:

```
        <div>
            <AppBar
                title="My App"
                iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
                onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
            />
            <TextField
                hintText="Hint goes here"
                floatingLabelText="Enter your Note here..."
                multiLine={true}
                fullWidth={true}
                rows={2}
            />
            <Drawer
                docked={false}
                open={this.state.open}
                onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
            >
                <MenuItem>One</MenuItem >
                <MenuItem>Two</MenuItem >
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
```

When I load this up on my phone, it doesn't adjust it's size as I had hoped. Is there any way to make this responsive using only material-ui? If not, is there any way I can use Bootstrap or some other package for responsiveness?

Thanks,
-Jim

Comment: How material-ui demo site worked in same environment? The drawer itself not such big width and fit to mobile isn't it? What is about another components like appbar?

Comment: Yes, the material-ui site itself seems to be responsive. But it's hard to tell what they did to make it responsive. I didn't see any reference to any Bootstrap libraries in the source code

Comment: So this is happiness that there is not bootstrap. Let it be known to you that responsiveness is achieved through css and js (rather than bootstrap)

Comment: @jbambrough What version of material-ui do you use, 4 or 5?

Answer (score 1):

I made a complete example for it and it is totally responsive [here in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-kowalevski-ktzi3?file=/src/App.js)

you should put your main pages on a box like this :

```
   <Box
            component="main"
            sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
            className={classes.content}
            style={{ width: "calc(100% - 240px)" }}
          >
<TextField
                hintText="Hint goes here"
                floatingLabelText="Enter your Note here..."
                multiLine={true}
                fullWidth={true}
                rows={2}
            />
</Box>
```

this topic is bigger than I could write all code here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Material ui has also a responsive drawer
here is the link to documentation

https://mui.com/components/drawers/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are in need of the material-ui useMediaQuery: https://mui.com/components/use-media-query/

Summary of how I set it up in my application using functional components:

**1)** Created two constants one useMediaQuery to detect the current screen resolution, second a useState that we will use to turn the drawer to an open or closed position depending on the screen resolution

**2)** Implemented a useEffect hook to reRender anytime the useMediaQuery const changes value. If larger than a medium screen resolution, set the sideBar to open. If not, turn it to a closed position.

**3)** You should be able to test this in your browser by making your browser bigger and smaller and seeing it open and close responsively. This same useMediaQuery process can be used for any material ui component to make it responsive to screen size.

Hopefully this helps!

```
const Main = observer((): JSX.Element => {
/* You can use standard pixel sizes (e.g. 900px) if desired instead of sm, md, lg */
const md = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md')); 
const [appBarOpen, setAppBarOpen] = useState(true);


/* Collapse the side drawer if the screen size is medium or lower. Have it open 
if screen size is above medium */
useEffect(() => {
    setAppBarOpen(md === false ? false : true);
}, [md]);

return(
    <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
            <Typography variant="h4">Menu</Typography>
        <SideBar open={appBarOpen} />
    </Drawer>;
    )
```